# Ring of fractions $S^{-1}A$ and localisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me with the problem 6.4 Reid (Undergraduate commutative algebra), because I've been trying to get the solutions for days and I don't see it.

(a) 
Give an example of a ring $A$ and distinct multiplicative subset $S$, $T$ so that $S^{-1}A=T^{-1}A$.

(b)
Prove that for fixed $S$, there is a maximal multiplicative set $T$ with this property, defined by
$T=\{t \in A :at\in S \mbox{ for some } a\in A\}$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints

(a) Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{2^n:n\ge0, n\ne1\}$; then $2\notin S$, but $2$ is invertible in $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$.

(b) Prove “$T$ is a multiplicative set and $S^{-1}A=T^{-1}A$”; next prove that this can't hold for any multiplicative set properly containing $T$.

Comment: in some books 1 belongs to a multiplicative set.Anthony! what about yours

Comment: I consider 1 always belongs to a multiplicative set.

Comment: @Anthony Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{2^n:n\ge0,n\ne1\}$. This is multiplicative, but $2\notin S$.

Comment: @egreg What Anthony ment was that in his context multiplicative sets contain $1$ by definition of *multiplicative set*.

Comment: @Christoph That's why I proposed a different example; I replaced the original one with the one in my comment.